# jQuery preload URL

Tags: jquery, preload

I'm looking for a solution to preload the content of a page if someone clicks on a link because I'm mainly generating the page content dynamically.

For example:

```
<a href="pagexy.php">click me</a>

    $('a').click(function{
    
       $('#preloader').show();
    
       $preloadurl($(this).attr('href')){
          done: // Open the URL / show the content
       }
    });
```

Is there any plugin which makes this possible?
It would be nice if that would work with a form submit, too.

Answer (score 0):

For my gallery site, i always use the [QueryLoader2](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/) Plugin by Gaya Design.

It looks nice and is easy-to use. Hope you search something like that.

Here's a demo: http://gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader2/

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I already take a look at QueryLoader2 but i want to show a loader on the old page and open the new page after the content is loaded dynamicly.

Comment: Then take a look at Ajax / jQuery.ajax

Comment: It's no problem for me to develop it by myself but i've hoped that there is already a plugin for this to save time... Anyway... thank  for answering, i guess i have to code it by myself.

Comment: Oh ok. No sorry, i don't know any plugin. Happy Coding